# Is there any way for other users to run an app script without logging in?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written two very simple scripts to collect some data from a small team. Below is the entire code.

```
function recordProgress(){
  var sps = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shUser = sps.getSheetByName("User");
  var shData = sps.getSheetByName("Data");
  var lastrow = shData.getRange("I1").getValue();
  shData.getRange("A" + lastrow).setValue(shData.getRange("A" + lastrow).getRow());
  shData.getRange("B" + lastrow).setValue(shUser.getRange("D3").getValue());
  shData.getRange("C" + lastrow).setValue(shUser.getRange("D5").getValue());
  var str_a = shData.getRange("B" + lastrow).getDisplayValues();
  var str_b = ("000" + shData.getRange("C" + lastrow).getDisplayValues()).slice(-3);
  shData.getRange("D" + lastrow).setValue(str_a + "_" + str_b);
  shData.getRange("E" + lastrow).setValue(shUser.getRange("D29").getValue());
  shData.getRange("F" + lastrow).setValue(shUser.getRange("D27").getValue());
  shData.getRange("G" + lastrow).setValue(shUser.getRange("D31").getValue());
  shData.getRange("H" + lastrow).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd-mmm-yyyy");
  shUser.getRange("D3").clearContent();
  shUser.getRange("D5").clearContent();
  shUser.getRange("D27").clearContent();
  shUser.getRange("D29").clearContent();
  shUser.getRange("D31").clearContent();
}

function clearUser(){
  var sps = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shUser = sps.getSheetByName("User");
  shUser.getRange("D3").clearContent();
  shUser.getRange("D5").clearContent();
  shUser.getRange("D27").clearContent();
  shUser.getRange("D29").clearContent();
  shUser.getRange("D31").clearContent();
}
```

As you can see the codes perform very simple steps of getting user inputs from the sheet `User` to the sheet `Data` with some minor formatting. I can execute the codes easily and it works as expected. I have deployed it as a web app to execute as me for the purpose of sharing.

The problem starts when I share the sheet with edit rights to anyone with the link. The other users are not able to run the scripts on their end (tested by me by trying it on incognito).

Previously I had some codes for showing some ui alerts which I have now deleted as I read that those might be requiring log-in for authorizing the code run.

As a test I have logged in from another gmail account and sure enough, there I am presented with an authorization prompt.

I can't enforce other users to sign in to their gmail accounts for this. Is there any way that scripts can be used without forcing other users to sign in? Maybe there is still some element in my code that triggers an authorization prompt?

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution would be to [create a form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6281888) instead of sharing a spreadsheet for data input. Form responses automatically appear in a separate tab in the spreadsheet in a row-oriented fashion.

If necessary, you can customize a form with at a paid tool such as [Formfacade](https://formfacade.com).